# What is the Simplest Way to Reverse an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

What is the simplest way to reverse this ArrayList?

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();

//Add elements to ArrayList object
aList.add("1");
aList.add("2");
aList.add("3");
aList.add("4");
aList.add("5");

while (aList.listIterator().hasPrevious())
  Log.d("reverse", "" + aList.listIterator().previous());
```

Answer (score 889, accepted):

```
Collections.reverse(aList);
```

Example ([Reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ReverseorderofallelementsofJavaArrayList.htm)):

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
//Add elements to ArrayList object
aList.add("1");
aList.add("2");
aList.add("3");
aList.add("4");
aList.add("5");
Collections.reverse(aList);
System.out.println("After Reverse Order, ArrayList Contains : " + aList);
```

Comment: @AgarwalShankar i am getting an error required ArrayList found void. Am i missing something.

Comment: @SagarDevanga The list is reversed in place, not returned.

Comment: Collections.reverse(List); 
I used it in an Android project, works fine.

Answer (score 23):

The trick here is defining "reverse". One can modify the list in place, create a copy in reverse order, or create a view in reversed order.

The simplest way, *intuitively speaking*, is `Collections.reverse`:

```
Collections.reverse(myList);
```

This method *modifies the list in place*. That is, `Collections.reverse` takes the list and *overwrites* its elements, leaving no unreversed copy behind. This is suitable for some use cases, but not for others; furthermore, it assumes the list is modifiable. If this is acceptable, we're good.

---

If not, one could *create a copy in reverse order*:

```
static <T> List<T> reverse(final List<T> list) {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.reverse(result);
    return result;
}
```

This approach works, but requires iterating over the list twice. The copy constructor (`new ArrayList<>(list)`) iterates over the list, and so does `Collections.reverse`. We can rewrite this method to iterate only once, if we're so inclined:

```
static <T> List<T> reverse(final List<T> list) {
    final int size = list.size();
    final int last = size - 1;

    // create a new list, with exactly enough initial capacity to hold the (reversed) list
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(size);

    // iterate through the list in reverse order and append to the result
    for (int i = last; i >= 0; --i) {
        final T element = list.get(i);
        result.add(element);
    }

    // result now holds a reversed copy of the original list
    return result;
}
```

This is more efficient, but also more verbose.

Alternatively, we can rewrite the above to use Java 8's `stream` API, which *some people* find more concise and legible than the above:

```
static <T> List<T> reverse(final List<T> list) {
    final int last = list.size() - 1;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, last) // a stream of all valid indexes into the list
        .map(i -> (last - i))             // reverse order
        .mapToObj(list::get)              // map each index to a list element
        .collect(Collectors.toList());    // wrap them up in a list
}
```

nb. that `Collectors.toList()` makes very few guarantees about the result list. If you want to ensure the result comes back as an ArrayList, use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead.

---

The third option is to *create a view in reversed order*. This is a more complicated solution, and worthy of further reading/its own question. Guava's [Lists#reverse](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) method is a viable starting point.

Choosing a "simplest" implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Tysvm for being so thorough in your answer. It saved me time trying to work this out (your third solution).

Answer (score 22):

Not the simplest way but if you're a fan of recursion you might be interested in the following method to reverse an ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Object> reverse(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    if(list.size() > 1) {                   
        Object value = list.remove(0);
        reverse(list);
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Or non-recursively:

```
public ArrayList<Object> reverse(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    for(int i = 0, j = list.size() - 1; i < j; i++) {
        list.add(i, list.remove(j));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but in your non-recursive example, doesn't `int j` not get updated with each iteration? You initialize it to `j = list.size() - 1` but I don't think that _initialization_ section of the `for loop` gets updated with each iteration does it?

Comment: @Turbo j doesn't need to be updated with each iteration.  It is initialized to the last index of the ArrayList and is used to access the last element.  Inside the for loop the last element is removed and inserted into index i; i is incremented until it reaches the next to last position in the ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, but on the second iteration, won't you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since you're trying to access `j` (the last index of the original ArrayList) but you already removed the object at that index?

Comment: Sorry, just ran the code, definitely works. I forgot that `add()` pushes the other elements down the array, so the array stays a constant size essentially. Interesting solutions, thanks!

Comment: Also, just curious but how did you come up with the recursive method? I don't think that's something I would normally think of.

Comment: interesting approach, another way to reverse the ArrayList. remove last one and save last value to the first, util traverse every node of the list. but it requires two operations -add and remove. it works when you have limited space.

Comment: Performance! Calling `.remove(0)` on an `ArrayList` is the first red flag, that's a linear shuffle there, so this is O(N^2) right off the bat. Also, transferring the entire list (heap data) to the stack won't scale: it's a stack overflow exception waiting to happen (once you get past the minute+ delay of this running). Recursive methods are best when they break down the task into smaller problems. Really, just use the provided libraries for such a simple task.

Comment: @LukeUsherwood I agree it's not efficient but that wasn't the question.  The question was for the simplest way and the recursive approach is about as simple as it gets to implement it yourself.

Comment: Doing this recursive reverse is just a stack overflow waiting to happen.

Answer (score 7):

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

myArray.add(1);
myArray.add(2);
myArray.add(3);

int reverseArrayCounter = myArray.size() - 1;

for (int i = reverseArrayCounter; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(myArray.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution without using extra ArrayList or combination of add() and remove() methods. Both can have negative impact if you have to reverse a huge list.

```
 public ArrayList<Object> reverse(ArrayList<Object> list) {

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; i++) {
     Object temp = list.get(i);
     list.set(i, list.get(list.size() - i - 1));
     list.set(list.size() - i - 1, temp);
   }

   return list;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 21 you can use `ArrayList#reversed()`. Where `ArrayList` implements `SequencedCollection`.

This is part of [Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) added to the Collections framework.

Answer (score 3):

We can also do the same using java 8.

```
public static<T> List<T> reverseList(List<T> list) {
        List<T> reverse = new ArrayList<>(list.size());

        list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
                .descendingIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(reverse::add);

        return reverse;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reversing a ArrayList in a recursive way and without creating a new list for adding elements :

```
   public class ListUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("1");
        arrayList.add("2");
        arrayList.add("3");
        arrayList.add("4");
        arrayList.add("5");
        System.out.println("Reverse Order: " + reverse(arrayList));

    }

    public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> arrayList) {
        return reverse(arrayList,0,arrayList.size()-1);
    }
    public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> arrayList,int startIndex,int lastIndex) {

        if(startIndex<lastIndex) {
            T t=arrayList.get(lastIndex);
            arrayList.set(lastIndex,arrayList.get(startIndex));
            arrayList.set(startIndex,t);
            startIndex++;
            lastIndex--;
            reverse(arrayList,startIndex,lastIndex);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case we are using **Java 8**, then we can make use of Stream. The ArrayList is random access list and we can get a stream of elements in reverse order and then collect it into a new `ArrayList`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> someDummyList = getDummyList();
        System.out.println(someDummyList);
        int size = someDummyList.size() - 1;
        ArrayList<String> someDummyListRev = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,size).mapToObj(i->someDummyList.get(size-i)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        System.out.println(someDummyListRev);
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> getDummyList() {
        ArrayList dummyList = new ArrayList();
        //Add elements to ArrayList object
        dummyList.add("A");
        dummyList.add("B");
        dummyList.add("C");
        dummyList.add("D");
        return dummyList;
    }
```

The above approach is not suitable for LinkedList as that is not random-access. We can also make use of `instanceof` to check as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin Users**

```
val reverse: List<Int> = list.reversed();
```

Happy Coding!

[Reference](https://www.techiedelight.com/reverse-copy-list-kotlin/)

Answer (score 0):

A little more readable :)

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> reverse(ArrayList<T> list) {
    int length = list.size();
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(length);

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result.add(list.get(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another recursive solution

```
 public static String reverse(ArrayList<Float> list) {
   if (list.size() == 1) {
       return " " +list.get(0);
   }
   else {
       return " "+ list.remove(list.size() - 1) + reverse(list);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

**2023 Edition for Kotlin**

**asReversed**

Returns a reversed read-only view of the original List. All changes made in the original list will be reflected in the reversed one.

```
val original = mutableListOf('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
val originalReadOnly = original as List<Char>
    val reversed = originalReadOnly.asReversed()

println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e]
println(reversed) // [e, d, c, b, a]

// changing the original list affects its reversed view
original.add('f')
println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
println(reversed) // [f, e, d, c, b, a]

original[original.lastIndex] = 'z'
println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e, z]
println(reversed) // [z, e, d, c, b, a]
```

**reversed**

Returns a list with elements in reversed order.

```
val myList = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(myList.reversed())    // [3, 2, 1]
```