# Replace a list with the numbers in another list after rearranging

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been having trouble with the next thing: I have an arraylist with numbers in it, and I want to reverse the numbers in the list, as in, if it had 1 2 3, replace the values in the arraylist with 3 2 1. To that end, I created a method called reordenar(); which puts the last number in the first arraylist in the first spot in the second arraylist. After this is done, I don't know how to make the first arraylist get its numbers replaced by the second. Here's the code I've written.

```
package firstPackage;
import java.util.*;

public class firstMain {

    public static Object reordenar(List n){
        List secondList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i=0; i<n.size(); i++){
            secondList.add(n.size()-i);
        }
        return n;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List firstList = new ArrayList();
        firstList.add("1");
        firstList.add("2");
        firstList.add("3");
        firstList.add("7");
        firstList.add("5");
        firstList.add("6");
        firstList.add("9");
        reordenar(firstList);
        System.out.println(firstList);

    }

}
```

that code just prints out the normal order, not the rearranged one. thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is this an assignment to write your own reverse method? If not, I would look at `Collections.reverse(firstList)`

Comment: Also, have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766492/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-an-arraylist

Comment: Yes, it's about writing my own reverse method, otherwise I would have used that method (I had googled it before). Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Oh, I just saw there was a iterative method  there after the Collections.reverse. Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 `ArrayList`s to make this work. Just iterate upto half the elements of your `ArrayList` and use a temporary variable to exchange places between the 1st and the last, the second and the second form the end etc.

Also it's not a good idea to use `ArrayList` without giving the specific type it will contain like:

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The former (without the specific type) implies `Object` for your `ArrayList` which usually is too wide to be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked, though using two ArrayLists was more intuitive for me since I'm not used to iteration