# Reverse an arraylist but the value of reversing array not saved in another arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an Arraylist named temp. There is some element within that arraylist. I want to reverse this Arraylist and store the value of this reverse list within another list. So, here is my code.

```
ArrayList <Integer> Temp=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Integer> ReverseTemp=new ArrayList<>();
Temp.add(5);
Temp.add(7);
Temp.add(1);
Temp.add(2);
ReverseTemp=Collections.reverse(Temp);
```

There is an error in this line. It says, Required Arraylist get void. So how could I save the value of my reverse Temp list within another arraylist. Is it possible to save this `Collection.reverse(Temp)` within another 1-D array?

Comment: `Collections.reverse(Temp);` doesnt return an ArrayList. it returns `void`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766492/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-an-arraylist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Simplest Way to Reverse an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766492/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.reverse()` doesn't return a new list; it reverses the list you pass to it. If you want a new list, make a copy first, then call `reverse()`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
temp.add(5);
temp.add(7);
temp.add(1);
temp.add(2);
ArrayList<Integer> reverseTemp = new ArrayList<>(temp);
Collections.reverse(reverseTemp);
```

Comment: I want to reverse an arraylist then save the value to another arraylist.Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I showed you how to copy a list, and how to reverse a list. What else do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second ArrayList. Just use

```
Collections.reverse(Temp);
```